# Dandelion++ for Bitcoin

Tags: privacy, full-node, p2p, dandelion

Dandelion BIP: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0156.mediawiki

The article that I read about Dandelion++: https://www.monerooutreach.org/stories/dandelion.html

It mentioned that Dandelion++ was developed for Bitcoin. So do we have a BIP for it and plan to implement in Bitcoin Core?

> Though Dandelion++ was explicitly developed for Bitcoin, it was recently applied to Monero by developer Lee Clagett (vtnerd), with testing and review by developer moneromooo

Comment: There is a bip. https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0156.mediawiki

Comment: That's Dandelion. The question is about Dandelion++

Comment: And just realized we don't even have Dandelion in Bitcoin Core: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13947#issuecomment-513858189

Comment: I haven't looked into it but Dandelion++ may be addressing some of the problems with Dandelion. Dandelion++ doesn't necessarily mean Dandelion implemented first and then Dandelion++. As far as I understand Dandelion is dead for some of these reasons https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81503/what-is-the-tradeoff-between-privacy-and-implementation-complexity-of-dandelion

Comment: @MichaelFolkson I think BIP 156 is for Dandelion++ as darosior mentioned. Still reading everything and maybe will try few things today.