# Is it possible to determine what node a transaction originated from?

Tags: transactions, privacy

Let's say `node-A` is propagating a transaction to it's peers on the network: `node-B`, `node-C`, etc. Is there any way for the other nodes to know that `node-A` is the *originator* of that transaction, as opposed to simply being a *source of gossip* about the transaction ("gossip" e.g. `node-B` sharing the transaction with `node-C`)?

It seems like it would be very important privacy-wise for the originator of the transaction to be obfuscated by appearing on-network in exactly the same way as nodes who gossip about the transaction. But I am not sure how things stand in the bitcoin protocol. Are all relayings of transactions created equal, or are some recognizable as the original source of transmission to the network?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any services that can reasonably guess what IP address a transaction originated from?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75596/are-there-any-services-that-can-reasonably-guess-what-ip-address-a-transaction-o)

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a problem. While node-B and C cannot be sure that node-A is the originator, if they both belong to the same spy they can be increasingly confident if they have many other connections and both receive the transaction from node-A first.

This kind of attack has long been recognized and it is certainly being actively exploited by many blockchain analysis companies. There is research (see [Dandelion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04439) and further developments of this idea) on how to make this attack harder, but it has some other tradeoffs and hasn't been included in bitcoin-core yet AFAIK.

Comment: Indeed, the Dandelion proposal is no longer pursued to be added to Bitcoin Core due to DOS attack concerns: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81503/5406